# Cleaning up printing of command-line prompt (Java)

Tags: java, io, coding-style

I'm trying to write an interactive prompt in Java. More specifically, something like the following:

```
>>> load names;
>>> print names;
```

(i.e. it prints the `>>>` on each line and then the user enters the command. I have written the following Java code to accomplish this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String command;
        System.out.print(">>> ");
        while ((command = r.readLine()) != null) {
            processCommand(command);
            System.out.print(">>> ");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
    }
}
```

My question: is there a cleaner way to do this? I don't like the idea of having to print the prompt (`>>>`) in multiple places, and I feel like there should be an easy way to just have to do it once.

Any suggestions for cleaning this up?

Comment: Just use [`Console.readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)). No need to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You want to change that loop to a do while so you only have to print ">>>"? I'm not sure if I understand your question

Comment: Adding some detail to your question would help a lot. I'm not sure I understand what your issue is. From the way you worded, it sounds like you wrote a program with the intentions of it printing ">>>" on every line, and you don't want it to do it anymore. Why can't you just delete line 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing this

```
try {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String command = " ";
    while (command != null) {
        System.out.print(">>> ");
        command = r.readLine();
        processCommand(command);
    }
 } catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
 }
```

Comment: Anything wrong with [`Console.readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) which will display a prompt _and_ read the input. This seems to be reinventing the wheel. Also, **close your resources**.

Answer (score 0):

You could add to the bottom of `processComand`, `System.out.println(">>>");`

```
try {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String command = " ";
    do{
        command = r.readLine();
        processCommand(command);
    }while (command != null) 
 } catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
 }
```

Comment: Then there would be no prompt the first time through.